# How to Use Excel SUMIFS with Greater Than Or Equal Operator When Numbers Stored as Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a table where underlying database stores numbers as text.  In this case, the greater than or equal operator doesn't capture the first value.

This formula ignores the first row of the data in the result where AcctNum=123.  The formuula returns 11 when it should return 21.

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[Balance],Table1[AcctNum],">='123'", Table1[AcctNum],"<='500'")
```

[image]

Things I have tried:
1. "*" wildcard.
2. Many combinations of T() and TEXT() Function.

Things I don't want to do:
1. Use arrays.
2. Add columns to my table that are converted to numeric, because not all AcctNum's are formatted the same way, which is why they must remain text.
3. Use SUMPRODUCT because readability of formula is important in this case.

I have written a custom function to work around the problem, but I would like to know if there is a natural Excel solution.  I have read SUMIF and SUMIFS do not work well when numbers are stored or retrieved from database as text.  I am using Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Try SUMPRODUCT with double minuses to convert the text and booleans to numbers.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(--Table1[acctnum]>=123), --(--Table1[acctnum]<500), Table1[balance])
```

Comment: This is very clever and it works!  If I didn't have so many of these formulae in my model, I might use it, but syntax is too complicated for my scenario.  But I meant to ask the question as to how to do it with SUMIFS and should have indicated SUMPRODUCT was one of the solutions I was avoiding due to complexity of the formula.  This is not the exact answer I was seeking but it's a very elegant workaround.  I have searched this question to death on many websites and this is probably the best answer so far.  Almost a toss-up between this and the custom function I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 2. Add columns to my table that are converted to numeric, because not all AcctNum's are formatted the same way, which is why they must remain text?

You can do this with an array or a helper column, other than that, not sure if it's possible using SUMIFS.

Comment: Probably the most common answer to this question where posted elsewhere is to convert the text to numbers in other columns, but the purpose of the post was to learn how to use SUMIFS with numbers stored as text -- which comes up a lot in accounting systems.  I suspect it can't be done with SUMIFS or any equivalently simple syntax, but that's why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sumproduct, you can explicitly convert the text to numbers.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[Balance],--(Table1[AcctNum]+0>=123),--(Table1[AcctNum]+0<=500))
```

[image]

Comment: Is not SUMPRODUCT and Array type formula?  OP asked to avoid such, though I do not believe it possible with those restrictions.

Comment: It's a matter of interpretation. Array formula = entered with Ctrl + Shift + Enter or Array formula = performing calculations over arrays.

Comment: I'm sorry (!), I forgot to mention that I don't want to use SUMPRODUCT either.  I have now edited the question to include that parameter.  It's a clever workaround but model is very complicated and I need to keep it as readable and simple as possible for non-techies and future maintenance..  Making >= operator work with SUMIFS is my first choice.  Writing a custom function was my second choice.  Looking for way to do it with SUMIFS, but thanks for answer.

Comment: No, you won't be able to do this with Sumifs. That's why I suggested Sumproduct. Some scenarios just can't be done with a formula that uses a "simple" syntax. Some things, like this one, are a bit more complex and require a formula that is a bit more complex. If you don't want to educate your users, then by all means, write a UDF.